# Shifting unique values to the left and removing duplicated values in a string

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a function that takes the unique values in a string, shifts them all together to the left and then set the duplicated values as an empty string. I wanted my function to return how many values were changed into an empty string.

My array is 
    { "cindy" , "sasha" , "cindy" , "daisy" , "bear" , "bear" , "bear" }; but the code I have seems to be skipping over the "bear" once and only returning 2.

for example, I can't do it like this

```
int duplicaterase(string array[], int  n)
{
const auto end = array + n;
auto finish = end;
for (auto start = array; start != finish; ++start) {
    finish = std::remove(start+1, finish, *start);
}
std::fill(finish, end, std::string());
return static_cast<int>(end - finish);;
}
```

Comment: Is it a requirement to use C-style array to hold the strings?  It would be easier with a C++ `std::vector<std::string>`.  But Jonathan Mee came up with a nice way to do it with the array.

Comment: @JiveDadson Note that C++11 provides `begin` and `end` for use on arrays as well as containers, making this a fairly simple problem to solve *independent* of whether an array or container is used.

Comment: @Jonathan - I know that. I've kept up with all the latest developments since 1984. :- ) I was thinking about using push_back to put the empty strings on the end at the end. What a terrible sentence. Pay no attention to me. My brains are sleepy.

Comment: thanks for all the answer, but I forgot to mention I am trying to do this without using c++ function. So sorry :( –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the 2nd bear from position 4, the 3rd bear moved to that position and then you continue to look for bears from position 5 onward and you missed it. Try replacing the last `if` by `while` to continue removing bears before incrementing `j`.

Comment: Hi, I tried the while loop, but the program is returning a 4 instead of returning 3 as it should, do you know what else went wrong there?

Comment: `int end = n - 1;` and then later: `duplicates = n - end;` What if all duplicates1 were unique?

Comment: I thought I added that in my code, but it is off by one number.

Answer (score 3):

This can be simply accomplished using [`remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) in a `for`-loop:

```
auto finish = end(duplicates1);

for(auto start = begin(duplicates1); start != finish; ++start) finish = remove(next(start), finish, *start);
fill(finish, end(duplicates1), string());
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/b6JqYf)

---

The above solution preserves order, but truly the fastest solution would be to `sort` and use [`unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique):

```
sort(begin(duplicates1), end(duplicates1));
fill(unique(begin(duplicates1), end(duplicates1)), end(duplicates1), string());
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/uwxYjD)

Comment: thanks for all the answer, but I forgot to mention I am trying to do this without using c++ function. So sorry :(

Answer (score 3):

Following up on Jonathan Mee's answer, this is a C++ way of doing it.

```
#include <algorithm>
int removeDuplicatedValues(string array[], int  n)
{
    const auto end = array + n;
    auto finish = end;
    for (auto start = array; start != finish; ++start) {
        finish = std::remove(start+1, finish, *start);
    }
    std::fill(finish, end, std::string());
    return static_cast<int>(end - finish);;
}
```

Comment: worth noting that this has O(n^2) complexity. Don't use in production code.

Comment: @Cheerandhth - So is the OP's version. In this case, n^2 is 49.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf So I included an *O(n log n)* solution but it fails to preserve order. I couldn't think of a simple way to preserve order and achieve *O(n log n)*. Do you have a simple way? It's worth an upvote to me to see a clean answer!

Comment: @JohathanMee - Darn you. I need to go to sleep. Now I'll lie awake thinking up an answer.

Comment: @JonathanMee - I thought of a way to preserve order and O(n log n),  or maybe O(n), but it requires extra memory. Pfft.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf   I thought of a way to preserve order and O(n log n), or maybe O(n), but it requires extra memory. Pfft.

Comment: thanks for all the answer, but I forgot to mention I am trying to do this without using c++ function. So sorry :(

Comment: @alfred.  Then why is the question tagged C++?  My suspicion is that you are taking a course called C++ and the instructor is teaching C with cout.  Here's some interesting viewing: https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk